# How to share objects between different classes?

Tags: c#

so basically i have this:

```
namespace ciao
{
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        public Item[] gameObjects = new Item[5];
    }
}
```

where item is a class to do some stuff(for now i just gave it  a name property)
now what should i do if i want to use gameobjects inside any new future class i create ?

also as side question is it a bad practice to do so?

Comment: If the 'future' class (`F`) needs a reference to object `a` of type `A`, then create a constructor for `F` taking `A`. If F does not need it (i.e. it is optional) then do it with a property set method. Have a look at the factory patterns, choose the ones that fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you want to pass the `gameObjects` array as a parameter into new classes.

You can just create a class whose constructor has a parameter to accept an `Item` array like so. Please note that this is not the only way to achieve what you're asking.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Item[] gameObjects;

    public MyClass(Item[] gameObjects)
    {
        this.gameObjects = gameObjects
    }
}
```

Now you can reference the `gameObjects` array in future operations of the class.

From your example:

```
namespace ciao
{
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        public Item[] gameObjects = new Item[5];

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(gameObjects);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes ty this would work but is this efficient? i mean passing each time  a parameter is a common way to deal with it? isnt a sloppy mechanic for the many cases where you dont need to pass but just operate them?

for example lets say i want to draw or delete them all, i wouldnt want to pass the gameObjects to another class, i would just want to create a class that cycle to gameObjects.lenght and set some parameter or call other methods to draw/manipulate each of them

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment, but in the example above, it's just passing an array pointer. There isn't much performance to worry about. If you don't want to store the reference to the array in the class, then just create methods to use the operate on the array.

Comment: It's exceedingly efficient. You're assigning a reference to an existing array. It's very fast and low on memory use. For classes that you don't need the game objects then you simply don't pass them.

Comment: Please read your own posts, and edit them. If we don't understand what you have written we can not answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create properties inside your Item class and assign them via properties?

As for the side question, I'd look at performance, and it is dependent on what you are doing, so you could run some load tests to see whether it is efficient or not.

Answer (score 0):

From an [OOP view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), exposing public fields is a bad thing, as any external code can make the `gameObjects` point to a different array instance. Exposing mutable objects is even worse, as any external code can modify contents of your array.

This is probably the most efficient way to move information around, more efficient of that being only to make it a public static field, which would make it an even greater maintenance nightmare than this. So, not only you shouldn't think of performance costs of passing stuff around, you should on the contrary concentrate on hiding stuff as much as you can.

You should start by defining which information you need from the a class, and program through **interfaces**. Do you need this information from your `Game1` class? Should this data be encapsulated into a different class?

Does your `Game1` class really need to instantiate these items? Or should they be instantiated outside and then passed to `Game1` and other classes?

Comment: ok thnx to all the answers i think i got it